# Repeat R script for many times and save results to text file

Tags: r

My script eventually gives me a matrix at the end and I need save it to a text file. How can I run this script for 100 times and save all the matrices using different names, e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 100?

Comment: Use for loop: `for (i in 1:100) {Matrix <- Script; write.table(Matrix, paste0("Matrix_", i, ".txt")) }`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My script has hundreds of lines. You meant to put that code at the end of my script? And the "Script" meant the name of my script?

Comment: Put your script to a function and name that function as you want, eg `Script`

Comment: I've tried and it worked! Thank you :)

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer, if it solved your problem you can accept it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple `for` loop. Move you script to a function and name it `Script`:

```
for (i in 1:100) {
    Matrix <- Script()
    write.table(Matrix, paste0("Matrix_", i, ".txt"))
}
```